# localStorage value set from inAppBrowser not showing outside - cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage, inappbrowser

I'm setting up localStorage from inAppBrowser view. Suppose inside the inAppBrowser view I've set

```
localStorage.setItem("page","10");
```

Inside inAppBrowser I want to check if the value is set , so I checked with

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("page"));
```

It's showing 10. Now I closed the inAppBrowser view and back to my main view. Then again I am giving

```
 alert(localStorage.getItem("page"));
```

to check the value in exit event listener. It's showing null or different past value but not 10. Can you please tell me what's wrong?????????

I've also tried with `window.localStorage.setItem("page","10");`

Basically I wanted to get a value from the inAppBrowser view. I tried the `setInterval and executeScript` example, but there is a problem in that example. When you do some heavy work inside inAppBrowser that consumes lot of memory, previous activity/webpage gets killed or hanged. Thus that is not efficient. Is there any simple way to work with localStorage and inAppBrowser OR to get get a value from inAppBrowser to main page?

Comment: localStorage is limited to the same domain policy.

Comment: it wont work like that, it's like youd want to have a cookie in one card of browser available in another card. inappbrowser is another 'instance' of browser, independent from phonegap webview, you can at most inject some script from phonegap into inappbrowser but cant do it in the opposite way. You can do some POST from the website your opening in inappbrowser and then GET it in your app.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher ah ok, got it. Thanks. So I need to drop the idea with localStorage and start finding something new.

Comment: I've not played enough with cordova/phonegap to recommend another solution, but it sounds like the sort of thing that would have been discussed here on StackOverflow.  Might want to search it.

Comment: @MarcinMikołajczyk Okay! got that. But did you mean $_POST $_GET?? I read somewhere that php function can't work with phonegap without remote server. Can you tell me an example how can interact with my local pages inside phonegap to communicate using POST GET!

Comment: ofcourse it can't work without remote server, this is the approach for phonegap development - app which is client talking with server via POST/GET requests. Why do you need the inappbrowser btw? seems like you dont really understand how should phonegap app work.

Comment: @MarcinMikołajczyk inAppBrowser is required for zooming image. I need to zoom an image which lies in a local page. But image can be dynamically changed inside that page. So after completion of viewing or when user closes the inAppBrowser I need the name of the image in the main page that was viewed last.

Comment: I dont exactly understand, inappbrowser is to open EXTERNAL webpage, not to show something that you have LOCALLY (on your phone) and using it to view an image is not good I guess. can't you just load the image into the <img src="http://images.url.com"> ?

Comment: You miss the `zoom` part of my comment. Through inAppBrowser I'm able to zoom the image that I can not do with cordova main view. I won't use iScroll and I didn't find any other zooming option with JQM that could work for me. Zooming image through inAppBrowser was suggested in a Stackoverflow question. And seriously!! you are thinking too hard for 'what this! why that!' I just need if it's possible to communicate between cordova main view and local page inside inAppBrowser. Good or bad, I'll handle that. Thank you so much for trying. @MarcinMikołajczyk

Comment: understanding context of what youre trying to achieve makes it easier to suggest something. Anyway, the only thing I can think of is 
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); }); - You will have the URL of the image in event object after page finishes loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as Jeremy J Starcher & Marcin Mikołajczyk commented, it's not possible. It's because of the same domain policy and inAppBrowser is a new instance which doesn't allow the previous webview to access it.

Solution is to send back the required data in main view or parent webview and then put them in localStorage.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this nice blog post, where communication between main view and InAppBrowser is discussed:

http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova%27s-inappbrowser

Basically, it's done by injecting JavaScript into InAppBrowser for evaluation and catching the result.